# How to get the TagName and TextContent of the XML textNode?

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I faced one exception while trying to get the tagname of the textnode of an XML document.

I wanted to get the tagName and the TextContent of all the node elements of one XML file.

```
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("RESOURCE_INFO");
NodeList head = nList.item(0).getChildNodes();
for(int j=0;j<head.getLength();j++){
     String p=head.item(j).getNodeName();
     String p=head.item(j).getNodeValue();
     String v=head.item(j).getTextContent();
}
```

But from none of the above I could not get the TagName. So changed the code like this..

```
String p=((Element)head.item(j)).getTagName();
```

Even though it was compiled, it produced the runtime error.

```
  SEVERE: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredTextImpl cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Element
```

This is the XML document

```
<TOTALRESOURCES>
  <RESOURCE_INFO>
    <HEADNODE>
       <HOST_NAME>xencluster</HOST_NAME>
       <HYPER_TYPE>XEN</HYPER_TYPE>
       <DOMAIN_COUNT>1</DOMAIN_COUNT>
       <TOTAL_MEM_MB>1015</TOTAL_MEM_MB>
       <TOTALNODES>6</TOTALNODES>
       <FREENODES>2</FREENODES>
    </HEADNODE>
    <COMPUTENODE>
        <HOST_NAME>xencluster</HOST_NAME>
       <HYPER_TYPE>XEN</HYPER_TYPE>
       <DOMAIN_COUNT>1</DOMAIN_COUNT>
       <TOTAL_MEM_MB>1015</TOTAL_MEM_MB>
    <COMPUTENODE>
    <COMPUTENODE>
        <HOST_NAME>xencluster2</HOST_NAME>
       <HYPER_TYPE>XEN</HYPER_TYPE>
       <DOMAIN_COUNT>2</DOMAIN_COUNT>
       <TOTAL_MEM_MB>1015</TOTAL_MEM_MB>
    <COMPUTENODE>
    </RESOURCE_INFO>
</TOTALRESOURCES>
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem, you may use SAX parser.